# Localization doesn't work after submitted app to apple

Tags: xcode, ios7, localization

Some time ago I decided to translate my app in two languages​​: Italian and English.

I read something about localizable.string and after several tests, both on the simulator and on my device I sent the application for review.

Today, the app has been approved and is available on the store, the problem is that now the texts are always in Italian even if i set the language in English, German or Russian!

Did any of you ever had a similar problem?

PS: I didn't send the wrong version because I also fixed several bugs and now they are not present.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your app doesn't react to changes in the language setting, which is a rather harmless problem and most customers would never notice.

You may have started it with your device set to Italian and it displayed Italian. To display English, you may have to close the application, change the language settings, and start the application again. If that doesn't work then you have a more serious problem. When you develop your app and start it from Xcode, it's always started new, so you might not have noticed.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried to change language and restart the app and doesn't work, do you have any other idea?